# Get ComputerName/IP in DB2

Tags: db2

I need to get info about user connected to my DB2. How can I get (if I can) computer name/login or IP of that user? I can get `host_name`, `current user` and login to DB2, but I want more specific information like IP or computer name. 
How I can do this?

Comment: What DB2 version and platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get that information from the MON_GET_CONNECTION table function.

The table functions have change a lot in the last versions, so it depends on your DB2 version what values you can get.

```
SELECT application_handle, 
       CLIENT_USERID,
       CLIENT_WRKSTNNAME, 
       CLIENT_HOSTNAME, 
       CLIENT_IPADDR
FROM TABLE(MON_GET_CONNECTION(cast(NULL as bigint), -2)) AS t 
ORDER BY rows_returned DESC;
```

For example CLIENT_HOSTNAME and CLIENT_IPADDR does not work in v9.7

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0053938.html

Comment: Great! `CLIENT_WRKSTNNAME` is enougth for me. But. There is a table, how I can take only one current user's info?

Comment: Can you be more specific? and I think that is another question.

Comment: I need to get info about current user, ip or computer name. Your query gives me resultset of all connected users, but I need only one specific like: `SELECT APPLICATION_ID FROM sysibm.sysdummy1` but with `CLIENT_WRKSTNNAME'. I have tried this: `SELECT APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_HANDLE, CLIENT_WRKSTNNAME 
FROM TABLE(MON_GET_CONNECTION(cast(NULL as bigint), -2)) AS t 
WHERE APPLICATION_ID = (SELECT APPLICATION_ID FROM sysibm.sysdummy1` but still I get rowset.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain some useful data using the MetaData.
For example the following code:

```
ResultSet rS = dataSource.getConnection().getMetaData().getClientInfoProperties();
while(rS.next()){
    System.out.println("**************************************************");
    System.out.println("NAME: <" + rS.getString(1) + ">");
    System.out.println("MAX_LEN: <" + rS.getInt(2) + ">");
    System.out.println("DEFAULT_VALUE: <" + rS.getString(3) + ">");
    System.out.println("DESCRIPTION: <" + rS.getString(4) + ">");           
}
    System.out.println("**************************************************");
```

Should give you something close to this:

```
**************************************************
NAME: ApplicationName
MAX_LEN: 255
DEFAULT_VALUE: 
DESCRIPTION: The name of the application currently utilizing the connection. This is stored in DB2 special register CURRENT CLIENT_WRKSTNNAM.
**************************************************
NAME: ClientAccountingInformation
MAX_LEN: 255
DEFAULT_VALUE: 
DESCRIPTION: The value of the accounting string from the client information that is specified for the connection. This is stored in DB2 special register CURRENT CLINT_ACTNG
**************************************************
NAME: ClientHostname
MAX_LEN: 255
DEFAULT_VALUE: ADMIN-9XYZK
DESCRIPTION: The hostname of the computer the application using the connection is running on. This is stored in DB2 special register CURRENT CLINT_WRKSTNNAM
**************************************************
NAME: ClientUser
MAX_LEN: 255
DEFAULT_VALUE: 
DESCRIPTION: The name of the user that the application using the connection is performing work for. This is stored in DB2 special register CURRENT CLINT_USRID.
**************************************************
```

---

### Edit # 2

The DB_MEMBERS table function returns basic member information about a DB2 instance.

```
db2SelectStatement = "select * from table(SYSPROC.DB_MEMBERS()) as members";
```

This would output something like the following:

---

MEMBER_NUMBER-----------HOST_NAME--------------PARTITION_NUMBER------MEMBER_TYPE

---

0-------------------------member1.mycompany.com----------------0--------------------------D
1-------------------------member2.mycompany.com----------------0--------------------------C
7-------------------------member3.mycompany.com----------------0--------------------------D

You can select these columns:

```
MEMBER_NUMBER
HOST_NAME
PARTITION_NUMBER
MEMBER_TYPE
PORT_NUMBER
SWITCH_NAME
STATUS
```

I tested this on DB 10 and it's working, however I didn't test it on DB 9

Comment: I added new section, let me know if it make sense :)

Answer (score 0):

db2

```
select AGENT_ID as AGENT, 
       substr(APPL_NAME, 1, 30) as APP_NAME,
       substr(APPL_ID, 1, 40)as APP_IP_ADD,
       substr(CLIENT_NNAME, 1, 40)as CLIENT 
from sysibmadm.snapappl_info order by CLIENT_NNAME
```

Output

```
AGENT                APP_NAME                       APP_IP_ADD                               CLIENT
-------------------- ------------------------------ -------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
.....................................................................................................................................
```

341 record(s) selected.