# How to obtain some properties from a database using JDBC?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, properties, db2

I'm trying to get / set some properties like the following:

```
databaseName
portNumber
serverName
driverType
readOnly
```

from DB2 database.
How can I do that using java's JDBC?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377509/get-computername-ip-in-db2

Answer (score 0):

Try to get these details from the [Database Metadata](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html). You will have to figure out where DB2 puts these values....

Answer (score 0):

Try something like next:

```
// URL for data source
String url = "jdbc:db2://myhost:5021/mydb:" +
             "user=dbadm;password=dbadm;";

// Create connection
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

// Create the DatabaseMetaData object
DatabaseMetaData dbmtadta = con.getMetaData();

// Check the driver version
dmtadta.getDriverVersion();
```

Comment: There is no get for properties like the one I mentioned, which some are specific properties for DB2. Any idea?